# Why did Darth Sidious go to the Jedi Temple in Revenge of the Sith?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, revenge-of-the-sith

Shortly after Darth Vader killed many Jedi at the temple, Sidious goes there to speak with Vader.

The security recordings from within the Jedi Temple show him there. (Not sure why the Jedi need security recordings inside their own temple.)

Darth Sidious really didn't need to go to the temple just to speak with Vader. He could have summoned Vader back to his office or met him elsewhere.

Did he have any other purpose for going there?

Comment: An interesting question. I always assumed we were watching a hologram of Vader communicating with Sidious *via hologram* but the books and script all agree that **he was physically there**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel)), **Palpatine went to the Jedi Temple in order to procure the Sith Holocrons that were stored in lowest vaults of the temple.**

> *He would see his friend, his student, his brother, turn and kneel in
>   front of a black-cloaked Lord of the Sith.*
>
> *His head rang with a silent scream.*
>
> *“The traitors have been destroyed, Lord Sidious. And the archives are
>   secured. **Our ancient holocrons are again in the hands of the Sith.”***

The [Ultimate Star Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars) factbook also indicates that **Palpatine *personally* used the Jedi's communications array to send out a signal to lure in any Jedi who'd missed Order 66.**

> *Palpatine also broadcasts a false emergency transmission across space,
>   notifying distant Jedi that the war is over and instructing them to
>   return to the temple.*

---

Given that the Emperor subsequently turns the Jedi Temple into his Imperial Palace, it's certainly possible that he wanted to **[measure up for new curtains](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/measure_the_drapes)** and make sure the previous tenant had taken all their crap with them.

Comment: Measure up for new curtains? Yeah, who needs knowledge stored in ancient Sith holocrons when you can have new curtains instead?

Comment: @RichS - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/measuring_the_drapes

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant now.